# Forma más simple de listar en git los archivos conflictivos

Tags: git, conflictos

Sólo necesito la lista de los archivos conflictivos.

Existe algo más simple que:

```
git ls-files -u  | cut -f 2 | sort -u
```

o

```
git ls-files -u  | awk '{print $4}' | sort | uniq
```

?

Supongo que puedo configurar manualmente un alias para esto, sin embargo me pregunto las ventajas de hacer esto. Suelo escribir `shell loops` por ejemplo para auto-resolver conflictos, etc. Tal vez reemplazando ese `loop` agregándolo  al mergetool.cmd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma más simple para obtener una lista de archivos en conflicto sería:

```
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

Para configurar un Alias:

```
$ git config --global alias.conflictos "diff --name-only --diff-filter=U"
```

aunque también puedes agregarlo al archivo `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    conflictos = diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

Para usar el Alias, en lugar de escribir:

```
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

únicamente escribimos:

```
 $ git conflictos
```

Comment: ¿y como se usa el alias?

Comment: @rnd es broma, no creo que tu no sepas jeje.  En lugar de escribir $ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U , únicamente: $ git conflictos

Comment: La hostía, genial, esta no me la sabía.